# How to divide specific column with rest of columns

Tags: r, python-3.x, shell, awk, statistics

I have matrix like this (first column names rest are values, separator i tab):

```
name1 A1 B1 C1 D1
name2 A2 B2 C2 D2
```

Matrix could be huge (it is mean about hundreds rows and columns). It is allays same size. I can expect zero values.

I need output like this:

```
name1 A1 B1 C1 D1 A1/B1 A1/C1 A1/D1
name2 A2 B2 C2 D2 A2/B2 A2/C2 A2/D2
```

This combination save to new file. And then make another combination:

```
name1 A1 B1 C1 D1 B1/A1 B1/C1 B1/D1
name2 A2 B2 C2 D2 B2/A2 B2/C2 B2/D2
```

and so on so on => divide each column with rest of columns in matrix and save as TSV to new file. And also round to three decimal places.

I can do this manually with script:

```
awk '{OFS="\t"}{$6=$2/($3+0.001); $7=$2/($4+0.001); $8=$2/($5+0.001)}1' input_file.tsv
```

Reason why I add number 0.001 is that division by zero is impossible. I can create shell script with wile loop, but it takes long time.

I would be very happy for any automation this process.

Comment: The python [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library is excellent at performing mathematical operations on tables of data like this.

Comment: `pandas` is great indeed but for simple stuff like the task described on OP, it is overkill. The standard library module [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) can handle it very well.

Comment: Tagging 3 different languages is a good sign that the question is too broad. Maybe you can pick one and make an example with specific values in it?

Comment: @camille Yes this because I working in AWK, but try to switch to Python. R is probably best solution for this tasks - but I have no knowledge.

Comment: Just updated my answer and now it is agnostic about the number of columns. Can you give it a try? It will create files from `output_1.tsv` to `output_n.tsv` with `n` being the number of columns to operate on, and the contents of `output_n.tsv`, is `column_n / every other column`, ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with `python-3.x`, here is a script to achieve what you want (it requires Python 3.6+ though, because of `f-strings`):

```py
from pathlib import Path
import csv

source = Path('input.tsv')

with source.open() as src:
    csvreader = csv.reader(src, dialect='excel-tab')

    # get number of columns and rewind
    cols = len(next(csvreader)[1:])
    src.seek(0)

    csvwriters = []

    # create a csv.writer for each column
    for i in range(cols):
        # output_col_01.tsv, output_col_02.tsv ...
        csvwriters.append(
            csv.writer(
                Path(f'output_col_{i + 1:02d}.tsv').open('w'),
                dialect='excel-tab'
            )
        )

    nan = float('nan')

    for name, *cols in csvreader:
        for i, a in enumerate(cols):
            row = [name]
            for j, b in enumerate(cols):
                # skip the quotient of a col by itself
                if i != j:
                    a = float(a)
                    b = float(b)
                    # nan if division by zero
                    row.append(round(a / b, 4) if b else nan)

            csvwriters[i].writerow(row)
```

Instead of adding `0.001` for operations where the divisor is `0`, I opted to return `float('nan')`.

It will not divide a column by itself and will round the quotients to 4 decimal places.

Finally, if you are using a Python version earlier than 3.6 (but you will still need a Python version 3.4+, because of `pathlib.Path()`), then replace the following line:

```py
Path(f'output_col_{i + 1:02d}.tsv').open('w'),
```

with:

```py
Path('output_col_%02d.tsv' % (i + 1)).open('w'),
```

That's needed because `f-strings` were introduced in Python 3.6.

Comment: Thank you anyway! Still want to improve in my python and your lesson brings me lot of new knowledge!!!

Comment: Hi man, I just tried and it says Path(f'output_col_{i + 1}.tsv').open('w'), - SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Any idea?

Comment: @Paul, `f-strings` were introduced in Python 3.6. What Python version are you using? I can adapt the code to an earlier version.

Comment: Ouu thats my mistake I have version 3.5

Comment: Check the alternative I added by the end of the answer.

Comment: Hello, thank you.. Just tried to run and I have following error:     row.append(round(a / b if b else nan), 4)) SyntaxError: invalid syntax - maybe because of python 3.5?

Comment: Nope. It is an extra ")" at the end. Just remove it. Fixed on the answer.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry for very delay answer. I tried your modified script and still get error:  File "cnv_statistics.py", line 36, in <module>
    row.append(round(a / b if b else nan), 4)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: Replace that line with `row.append(round(a / b, 4) if b else nan)`.

Comment: Dear accdias, sorry for very late answer. Just updated python and it works everything fine!

Answer (score 5):

Could you please try following. Also by seeing your attempt I am assuming that your Input_file is delimited by space NOT by comma, if there is any other delimiter than space then add `BEGIN{FS=","}`(comma as an example) in following code too. Thanks to @accdias adding logic to remove control M characters too

```
awk '
{
   gsub(/\r/,"")
}
{
  nf=NF
  close(out_file)
  for(k=2;k<=nf;k++){
    out_file=""
    for(i=2;i<=nf;i++){
      if($i!=0){
         $(NF+1)=sprintf("%.03f",$k/$i)
      }
      else{
         $(NF+1)=sprintf("%s","NaN")
      }
    }
    out_file=k"field_out_file"
    print >> (out_file)
    NF=nf
  }
}'  Input_file
```

***What does code take care of:***

- It creates output file names as per field's name like `2field_out_file` means 2nd field is getting divided by all elements through out the Input_file/.
- In back-end all output files will be opened so `close` function is used to avoid errors like `too many files opened`.
- It checks about `0` value if anything is getting divided by zero it prints `NaN` in output.

Comment: It is an elaborate work preventing possible errors and/or exceptions in advance. Very readable and concise. BTW the generated results seem to include the self-quotients as `A1/A1`, `B1/B1` etc. If the OP accepts it, I don't mind at all. :)