# Calculate ration of each column and keep header

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, awk

Dear stackoverflow users,

I have input file TSV (tab separate) with > hundreds columns:

```
**more in.tsv:**

reg  A  B  C  D 
reg1 A1 B1 C1 D1
reg2 A2 B2 C2 D2
reg3 A3 B3 C3 D3
```

`A1-N` are **numeric** value a can be zero also. `reg`, `reg1-N` and `A-D` are **string**.

I would like to calculate ration of each numeric value and save it to a new file:

```
**more A.tsv**

reg  A/B   A/C   A/D 
reg1 A1/B1 A1/C1 A1/D1
reg2 A2/B2 A2/C2 A2/D2
reg3 A3/B3 A3/C3 A3/D3
```

But I need also keep first row - I need to know which column was divided other one.

And so on so on:

```
**more B.tsv**

reg  B/A   B/C   B/D 
reg1 B1/A1 B1/C1 B1/D1
reg2 B2/A2 B2/C2 B2/D2
reg3 B3/A3 B3/C3 B3/D3
```

I found very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878040/how-to-divide-specific-column-with-rest-of-columns), but it does not keep first row (header). And it does not save new file according name of first row (A.tsv, B.tsv and so on).

I also prefer solution in awk or python.

**This does not give me required output as described above:**

```
awk '
{
   gsub(/\r/,"")
}
{
  nf=NF
  close(out_file)
  for(k=2;k<=nf;k++){
    out_file=""
    for(i=2;i<=nf;i++){
      if($i!=0){
         $(NF+1)=sprintf("%.03f",$k/$i)
      }
      else{
         $(NF+1)=sprintf("%s","NaN")
      }
    }
    out_file=k"field_out_file"
    print >> (out_file)
    NF=nf
  }
}'  in.tsv
```

Real Data:

```
cat in.tsv 

region      S1  S2  S3  S4
NR_110122   159 179 176 202
NR_132125   102 153 88  106
NR_136154   331 429 251 360
NR_136302   89  134 96  103
NR_136302   110 148 97  117
```

And required output:

```
cat S1.tsv
reg         S1/S2       S1/S3    S1/S4
NR_132125   0.666667    1.15909  0.962264
NR_136154   0.771562    1.31873  0.919444
NR_136302   0.664179    0.927083 0.864078
NR_136302   0.743243    1.13402  0.940171
```

And for another variable

```
    cat S2.tsv
    reg         S2/S1       S2/S3    S2/S4
.
.
```

Comment: What do you mean does not work very well? what is failing?

Comment: `A1-N are numeric value`: Can you show sample of real input and expected output

Comment: `pandas` is designed for these kind of calculation

Comment: @anubhava I just Added real example. Numbers can be zero, so I need to avoid division by zero. And I also sub-sample my example to 4rows and 3 columns. I hope right now it is more clear.

Comment: So in case of denominator is zero, what is expected result?

Comment: @anubhava - could be just mark NA.

Comment: ok but `159/179` is `.88826815642458100558` not what you have shown.

Comment: @anubhava just for example three decimal places so 0.888.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
    printf "%s", $1
    for(i=3; i<=NF; i++)
       printf "%s%s", OFS, ($2 ~ /[^0-9]/ ? $2 "/" $i : ($i==0 ? "NA" : sprintf("%.3f", $n/$i) ))
    print ""
 }' file | column -t
```

```
region     S1/S2  S1/S3  S1/S4
NR_110122  0.888  0.903  0.787
NR_132125  0.667  1.159  0.962
NR_136154  0.772  1.319  0.919
NR_136302  0.664  0.927  0.864
NR_136302  0.743  1.134  0.940
```

---

For enhanced requirement in comment below, following code may be used:

```
awk 'function divn(n, i, fn) {
    fn=n ".tsv"
    printf "%s", $1 > fn
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)
       if (i != n)
          printf "%s%s", OFS, ($i ~ /[^0-9]/ ? $n "/" $i : ($i==0 ? "NA" : sprintf("%.3f", $n/$i) )) > fn
    print "" > fn
}
BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
      divn(i)
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much, thats seems works perfectly fine for S1/S2, S1/S3 and S1/S4. But Then (what is make little complicated) I need (as example) divide S2/S1, S2/S3, S2/S4 and so on.. And each result save to different file - for example S1.tsv (division S1/S2,S1/S3,S1/S4), S2.tsv (division S2/S1,S2/S3/S2/S4)... Just edited original question..

Comment: But if is complicated to skip division for example S2/S2 (S3/S3 and so on) - we can do this - it will be 1 and I can filter out it later.

Comment: I am not really understanding it well because `$1` is always a fixed string not even a number in your sample.

Comment: Thank you it seems it works perfectly fine. You are awesome! Could you make me please hint how to round numbers for three decimal? And you are right $ is fixed string - it was wrong explanation...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Python with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table("in.tsv", index_col="reg")
# Divide A by all columns starting from B
result = (df["A"] / df.loc[:, "B":].T).T
result.to_csv("out.tsv", sep='\t')
```